# Why doesn't a mapped page send a sigsegv?

Tags: c++, c, linux, mmap

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void signal_handler(int signal) {
    using namespace std;

    cout << "WE GET SIGNAL!" << endl; 
    exit(0);
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    int over_9000 = 9001;

    signal(SIGSEGV, signal_handler);
    int* mem_location = (int*)mmap(nullptr, getpagesize(), 
        PROT_READ, MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);

    int value = *((int*)0x20);      // This sends sig segv as expected
    *(mem_location) = over_9000;    // This sends something else?
}
```

In the program above, trying to read `0x20` sends a `SIGSEGV` as expected - which the signal handler catches. But when I try the same thing with a mapped page, it doesn't send a `SIGSEGV`? It sends something else and exits the application with code `138`.

Debugger says that it's a `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` as expected, but doesn't seem to send a catchable signal. What am I doing wrong?

Also: (Osx Mavericks if that makes a difference).

Comment: Assuming the right headers and so on, it produces a SIGSEGV here. Maybe you produce a self contained testcase that people can take, that compiles, and should reproduce.

Comment: Updated answer. And still not working on my side.

Comment: Why would someone vote to close this? It shows an attempt to ask a good question. If more info is necessary, ask!

Comment: If the memory is mapped, why would you expect to get a SIGSEGV? Though trying to write to the memory once you mapped it without PROT_WRITE could be an issue.

Comment: Memory was mmaped only with PROT_READ, and in Linux this should fail with SEGV. Don't know about OSX, but it should fail too.

Comment: @SanJacinto: The question was edited multiple times, in the original version not even compiling, and with no information at all about the environment. The later one is still missing mostly. So far I have not seen any indications that someone could reproduce it, quite a prerequisite for doing more than guesswork.

Comment: @plasmahh As of now, it's been edited 3 times. The only substantive edit was to add headers, and one simple copy/paste by the OP could have fixed it. Hardly worth a close vote, which means that the _question would go unanswered_.

Comment: Wow, harsh. I don't get what the down vote is for. I think it's a real question.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Additionally, I'm not sure that reproducibility is a prerequisite for posting to SO. If it is, then one could _never_ ask questions and have his assumptions corrected, as is playing out here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I got it this time :)
on my system (linux), "bash -c 'kill -l 138'" says SIGUSR1;
Based on https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/signal.3.html, it seems that on a mac it should return SIGBUS.
Is that it?

Comment: Winner, that does it. Why would that be a bus error though?

Comment: The linux manpage says writing to readonly memory gets a SIGSEGV; posix says nothing (unless I missed it), and the mac manpage seemd to say nothing as well (at least not on https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/mmap.2.html); my guess is that you're supposed to get **some** signal (SIGBUS,SIGSEGV, whatever), but it's just a guess - does anyone know better?

Comment: I've since discovered that a fault against an unmapped page (`SIGSEGV`) is different from a fault against a mapped *but protected* (`PROT_NONE`) page. At least on OSX this causes a `SIGBUS` maybe for distinction?

Comment: That makes sense, `SIGBUS` is less common than `SIGSEGV`, so one may take it as a hint that it's `mmap`-related. Still just a guess, but plausible.

Answer (score 1):

You have "exit(0);" in the signal handler; try adding some write() after each instruction and you'll see for yourself :)

edit: after reading Joseph Quinsey's answer, I feel the need to specify that I used "gcc -O0 -ggdb" (you know, when in debugging mode...)

Comment: I think what the OP is tryinig to say is that he tried to compile and run two programs, in each only one of the lines to segfault being active.

Comment: That's possible; I wrote my answer after trying to comment out the first bad access and getting sigsegv as expected (removing "exit(0)" was not funny)

Comment: Originally, I had the line as pause(), but I later changed it to exit(0) for sanity purposes. But the handler still doesn't fire in the second version.

Comment: FWIW, "the implementation shall not permit a write to succeed where PROT_WRITE has not been set" http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) - it doesn't say exactly how the write is disallowed

Answer (score 1):

The "working" line:

```
int value = *((int*)0x20);      // This sends sig segv as expected
```

in your latest version wouldn't work for me unless I added `volatile int value = ...`. I presume (but haven't checked) that this is because otherwise the compiler just optimizes the line out.

So perhaps if you add `volatile` to `int* mem_location`, you would get a signal.

For what it is worth, the second signal works for me, as expected.

Comment: As your expectation, or as his expectation? Are you seeing the same as he does, or something else?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: To clarify, I _cannot_ reproduce the OP's problem. The line `*(mem_location) = over_9000` does give a `SIGSEGV` on my system--not Osx Mavericks, as the OP later added.

Comment: Same here (linux); using clang3.3, anything above -O0 optimizes away that line